# toggle modal screen from header react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

Hi I want to toggle a transparent modal screen from the header button, im using hooks

Heres my stack component

```
function MyStack(props) {

  const [modalvisble, setModalvisble] = useState(false)
  ToggleModal = () => {
    console.log(modalvisble)
    setModalvisble(!modalvisble)
  }
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="MyTabs"
        screenOptions={{
          header: ({ ToggleModal }) => {
            return (
              <Header
              ToggleModal={()=>ToggleModal} 
              />
            )
          },
          cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.8)',},
          cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current: { progress } }) => ({
            cardStyle: {
              opacity: progress.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 0.5, 0.9, 1],
                outputRange: [0, 0.25, 0.7, 1],
              }),
              overlayStyle: {
                opacity: progress.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [0, .5],
                  extrapolate: 'identity',
                })
              }
            }
          })
        }}
        mode='modal'
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name="MyTabs"
          component={MyTabs}
          options={{
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="ModalScreen" component={ModalBar} modalvisble={modalvisble} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Header Component

```
function Header({ ToggleModal }) {

  //const navigation = useNavigation();
  // const toggleIsFocused = () => {
  //   selected ? navigation.navigate('Mytab') : navigation.navigate('ModalScreen')
  //   return toggleSelected;
  //  }
  return (
    <View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 30, marginRight: 20, }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', margin: 10, fontSize: 13 }}>User Name</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity

            //onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}            
            onPress={ ToggleModal}
          />

        </View>         
    </View>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

Modal Screen

```
function ModalBar({modalvisble}) {
  return (
    <Modal style={{ flex: 1, }} visible={modalvisble} />
  )
}
```

I try to pass function from parent component to child / or reverse, but still, do not work. 
Goal is like using the user name icon to open modal screen for some info, and press again to close modal screen, with same button.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First, `ToggleModal={()=>ToggleModal}` this won't actually call `ToggleModal` function. Instead you should write `ToggleModal={() => ToggleModal()}`, or just `ToggleModal={ToggleModal}`.

Second, you dont need to pass `({ ToggleModal }) => {...}` as an argument. `ToggleModal` function is already defined and visible.

Last, you need to use `setState(prevState => nextState)` form of `setState`, because otherwise `modalVisible` will always be seen as `true` in that function (it won't update, unless you use `useCallback`) and the function will always set it to `false`. Here's the code `setModalVisible(modalVisible => { return !modalVisible })`.